# galleria lighbox not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, lightbox, galleria

i am using galleria with lighbox option,its wokring fine with chrome and other browser but in mozilla it does not work.

```
<script> 
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  // Load the classic theme
  Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria.classic.min.js');

  // Initialize Galleria
  Galleria.run('#flexy_gallery', {

    showInfo:true,
    showCounter:false,

    // search flickr for "Cantonese food"
    flickr: 'search: cartoon',
    flickrOptions: {
      // sort by interestingness
      sort: 'interestingness-desc'
    },
    description : true , 

  });

  Galleria.configure({
    lightbox: true
  });   




}); 

</script>
```

i debug the galleria js and found it goes in one of the swipe function in mozilla fire fox and due to that it does not open lightbox

```
if ( swipe ) {

  //Mozilla goes inside this loop and due to this it does not call **_show** function


} else {

  //for other browser it goes inside this loop and works fine
  protoArray.push.call( this._queue, {
    index : index,
    rewind : rewind
  });
  if ( !this._queue.stalled ) {
    this._show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe: http://support.galleria.io/discussions/problems/11136-it-doesnt-work-on-last-mozilla-f . It was solved in galleria v1.3.6

Comment: I am already using galleria 1.4.2, but still issue in firefox for lightbox

Answer (score 0):

do it like:

```js
Galleria.configure({
    lightbox: true,
    swipe:false
  });
```